# Как сделать так чтобы бот отправлял только фотографию которую отправляю я, а не все

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from sqlighter import SQLighter


# задаем уровень логов
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db = SQLighter('db.db')



# Команда активации подписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)
    
    await message.answer("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку! Ждите, скоро выйдет актуальное расписание! =)")
 
@dp.message_handler(commands=['tbl']) 
async def subscribe(message: types.Message): 
    all_tbl = db.get_tbl() 
    tbls = [] 
    for i in all_tbl: 
        tbl = f'{i[0]}' 
        tbls.append(tbl) 
    await message.answer(text="\n".join(tbls))

# Команда отписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его с неактивной подпиской (запоминаем)
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы итак не подписаны.")
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Актуальное расписание на завтра.")
  

# получаем список подписчиков бота
        subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def spam_photo(message: types.Message):
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    users = db.get_subscriptions()
    for i in users:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=int(i[0]), photo=file_id)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await message.answer("ОТправка завершена")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['user']) 
async def spam_photo(message: types.Message):
    users = db.get_subscriptions()
    await message.answer(str(users[1]))

@dp.message_handler(commands=['Monday'])
async def send_ph(message: types.Message):
 await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo='AgACAgIAAxkBAANiZTeivUdrCN8WE8qn1inIjwrc2EkAAq7YMRtwnsFJikOvhsbhx1wBAAMCAAN5AAMwBA')
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['Thursday'])
async def send_ph(message: types.Message):
 await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo='AgACAgIAAxkBAANoZTevghT5xBWp77HCOY00WHEtOboAAj7ZMRtwnsFJQ9jUAfPsfiUBAAMCAAN5AAMwBA')
                
                

# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```